# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject contains keys starting with "@"

Tags: .net, json, linq, rest, lotus-domino

I have to parse JSON returned from Lotus Domino REST API in .net.
I use

```
dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myString);
```

and the data object is Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Jobject

```
[
 {
    "@href":"http://domsrv.webdev.local:80/dbname.nsf/api/data/collections/name/.LkpCust/unid/6F4F9DE95F81A696C12572F3003BBC52",
    "@link":
    {
      "rel":"document",
      "href":"http://domsrv.webdev.local:80/dbname.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/6F4F9DE95F81A696C12572F3003BBC52"
    },
    "@entryid":"10-6F4F9DE95F81A696C12572F3003BBC52",
    "@unid":"6F4F9DE95F81A696C12572F3003BBC52",
    "@noteid":"12ED2",
    "@position":"10",
    "@siblings":60613,
    "@form":".CompanyProfile",
    "CompanyName":"ACME Inc."
 }
]
```

This is surely a dumb question, but I cannot find a way to get any value from the data object apart from data.CompanyName.

data.CompanyName returns "ACME Inc."

while I do not know how to get values for @unid, @noteid , @position or for any of the other items whose key starts with "@" character

Answer (score 2):

Ok, YASADQ (Yet Another Self Answered Dumb Question)...

With a little more thinking maybe I would have avoided posting the question.

Instead of doing

```
data[i].@unid
```

which gives null because the @ char is something not recognized, I do

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject myObj = data[i];
string myVal = myObj.Property("@unid").ToString();
```

Done

Answer (score 1):

It's good to see you already found the solution for .net.  FWIW, you use a similar pattern when parsing a data service response in JavaScript.

Instead of this:

```
var myVal = myObj.@unid;
```

you have to do this:

```
var myVal = myObj['@unid'];
```